# Value output by formula - not sure why array formula EXCEL

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

[image]

Using the array formula below `{=MMULT(MMULT(C27:D27,(H27:I28)),TRANSPOSE(C27:D27))}` I get `35.05425707`.

Using the below array `{=(MMULT(C27:D27,(H27:I28)))}` I get `5.763564268`.

Although I understand perfectly how the second formula output the value of `5.763564268` I do not understand how the `35.05425707` was output. Can I ask for a step by step breakdown? Please find a view of the file below:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your formulas seem to reference rows 27 and 28, though your screenshots seem to be referencing different rows. It would be more useful if you posted copiable data, not pictures.

Answer (score 0):

MMULT is an array formula and the first MMULT actually results in an array of 2 values:

`=MMULT(B7:C7,G7:H8)` returns an array of `5.7636` & `5.8818`

When you do the second MMULT:

`=MMULT(MMULT(B7:C7,G7:H8),TRANSPOSE(B7:C7))`

You multiply `5.7636` by `2` and `5.8818` by `4`. Added up that results in `35.0544`.*

*(*I used the screenshot for reference and the numbers are not matching, since the values shown are rounded values*)

[image]

Comment: I would love to do that now but am waiting for my reputation to grow here so I can vote.